# setting gdb breakpoint selects a different set of constructors 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: linux, gdb, 32bit-64bit, breakpoints

I have the exact same source code/make file compiled natively on two machines:  Linux Fedora 16 32 bit and Linux Fedora 17 64 bit.

On the 32 bit machine:

```
(gdb) break FRS::FRS
Breakpoint 4 at 0x804ea29: file ntfs.cpp, line 751.
Breakpoint 5 at 0x804e18f: file ntfs.cpp, line 505.
warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.

GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.3.50.20110722-16.fc16)
```

On the 64 bit machine:

```
(gdb) break FRS::FRS
Breakpoint 1 at 0x407daf: file ntfs.cpp, line 751.

GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.4.50.20120120-54.fc17)
```

Using the knowledge from the 32 bit debugging session, I set the other breakpoint (and deleted the first one) to debug the proper function.  However, it executes differently and only hits that constructor twice for the same test case.  On the 32 bit environment it hits the breakpoint a dozen or so times.

```
FRS::FRS (MFT *Mft, uint32 MFTRef, bool shallow)   // this is line 505
{
        memset (this, 0, sizeof *this);
        ParentMFT = Mft;
        MFTReference = MFTRef;
        Volume  *vol = GetParentVolume ();

        frs_bytes = ParentMFT -> GetFRSSizeInBytes();
        frs_buf = new uint8 [frs_bytes];
        if (!frs_buf)
        {
                fprintf (stderr, "FRS: alloc(%u) err\n", frs_bytes);
                exit (1);
        }

        int     sects = ParentMFT->GetFRSSizeInSectors();       // sectors per FRS
        bool    rc;

        if (!MFTRef)
                rc = vol -> RelativeRead (frs_buf, ParentMFT->GetMFTStart(), sects);
        else
        {
                uint32 FirstLsn = Mft -> LogicalFromVirtual(MFTReference * sects);
                uint32 LastLsn  = Mft -> LogicalFromVirtual(MFTReference * sects + sects - 1);

                if (FirstLsn + sects - 1 == LastLsn)    // is contiguous?
                        rc = vol -> RelativeRead (frs_buf, FirstLsn, sects);    // optimize read
                else
                {       // not contiguous:  read sectors one at a time
                        for (int j = 0;  j < sects;  ++j)
                        {
          ... (170 more lines)


// copy constructor
FRS::FRS(FRS *frs)   // this is line 751
{
        int     j;
        *this = *frs;
        if (frs_buf)
        {
                frs_buf = new uint8 [frs_bytes];
                memcpy (frs_buf, frs -> frs_buf, frs_bytes);
        }

        DAttr = NULL;
        StreamList = NULL;
      ...  // 50 more lines
```

Is there something intrinsically different about 64 bit code that this function would be compiled away?  (It is a 204 line function, so I have truncated it after demonstrating it is non-trivial.)

What would explain why `gdb` doesn't "see" the same set of constructors, and why the code doesn't seem to get called as much—though why it would be different from "everything or nothing" is a mystery.

Comment: So the code you've shown is the function at line 505?  What is the signature of the other constructor?

Comment: @lxop:  Yes it is.  I have added the other constructor, a copy constructor.

Comment: Did you compile with optimization (-O different from -O0)?

Comment: @alk:  I don't specify any optimization, so it is whatever the default is.  It must be pretty low because single stepping through the code requires a lot of steps.  The makefile's rule for `.cpp.o` is `g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<`:  `CPPFLAGS` is not set and `CFLAGS` is set to `-g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` (for 64 bit file offset handling).

Comment: Are you sure it is related to 32 vs 64 bit issue? Have you tried downloading same version of GDB and executing in both the system. I feel it has to do with change in GDB parse and identifying behavior rather than 32/64 bit system.

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran:  I am not sure.  I have not had any luck getting an older gdb version to run the 64 bit test again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing different versions of gdb as well as different versions of gcc.  That is just too many variables.

Most likely it is debuginfo differences.  But it isn't really possible to say with just this information.

One thing to know is that the C++ ABI specifies multiple copies of constructors to be emitted.  There are "in-charge" and not-in-charge variants.  gdb will put breakpoints on all the ones it finds.

However, I think this can be affected by the debuginfo and other factors.  It is not always obvious what happens from source to executable...  You can use tools like "nm" and "readelf -wi" to dig through the symbols and debuginfo if you really want to find exactly why this happens.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this.  Yours is definitely the best answer.